# regex don't capture 1st character

Tags: regex

I want to capture every letter except the first letter in the string.
Example string: `The cat in the hat.`

I know to capture the first letter is `/[^]/` so I would want something like `/not [^]/`

Comment: If you are using a programming language, an easier way might be to substring your input.

Comment: Perhaps, [`(?s)(?:^.|(?!^)\G)\K.`](https://regex101.com/r/xK0vT3/1) (if PCRE is used) Or a [variation with a capturing group](https://regex101.com/r/xK0vT3/2) for other languages supporting \G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize a capture group with a basic regular expression.

```
^.(.*)
```

The capture group stores the match result ignoring the first character in the string.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/oG8tK7/1)

Answer (score 7):

Use a zero width positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=^.).*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jX9bX0/1)